# How to highlight tabs that contain fields with .has-error class (angular ui-bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angular-ui-bootstrap

i'm using tabs directives in my template file (all tabs are defined there). Each tab contains several fileds that belongs to form (this single form fields are splitted into several tabs). When the whole form is validated some fields might get class '.has-error'. How can i highlight (give special backgorund color) only those tabs that contain fields with '.has-error' class inside related tab content?

Comment: couldn't you just add css to those fields, e.g. `input.has-error {background: red;}`?

Comment: I think that he's trying to add style to the tabs, not the fields.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is as follows: Wrap each tab content in an `ng-form`:

```
    <div ng-form bind-validity="tab1Invalid">
      ...form controlls...
    </div>
```

Use the `bind-validity` directive from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916420/angular-formcontroller-validation/29917788#29917788) (or any equivalent way to pass form validity status to the parent).

Now add a class to the tab header according to the form validity:

```
  <tab>
    <tab-heading>
      <span ng-class="{boom: tab1Invalid}">...</span>
    </tab-heading>

    ...content...
  </tab>
```

A working solution [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rpQS4XA6tnd2BcQZAFNd?p=info).

Answer (score 0):

you can add a css class (in this case "my.tab") to your tab directive. Then you can accomplish it like this:

```
.my-tab .has-error {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

--- update ---

after recognizing that you didnt mean the actual controls but the tabs, I would suggest this solution:

Add a directive to each tab that watches the form's status. You could just watch the $valid property of the form and set your highlighting within the directive for your tab according to the $valid value. Value will be passed over by watch function.

--- update ---
didn't know about functionality stated in the other answer. Pretty perfect!